# Post the data with recaptcha verify using curl

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I need to post the form data using curl but when i submit those data we can't able to submit because of captcha (google recaptcha). So is there any way to submit the form data with captcha verify. (http://prntscr.com/mx4ooy)

Would you please help us to sort out this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. Using cURL to post to a webpage for task automation is wrong, you should use an API for that. Talk to the site operator to find out what APIs are available. However, I guess it's not in the site operator's interest that you spam their site. Since you don't show any effort yourself, nobody here is going to help you either, I hope. BTW: Read [tour] and [ask].

Comment: it is possible, but very very difficult (because google tried to make it impossible). i know of only 2 services that have managed to do this: www.deathbycaptcha.com /DeathByCaptcha and www.botmasterlabs.net / XRumer - and they have certainly not open-sourced their solutions. your best best is to use the DeathByCaptcha API

Answer (score 1):

No. The whole point of having a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is to prevent you from doing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to submit the data for particular page i already did via CURL and works fine but after so many attempts of same page now captcha is display and without captcha we can not post the data. so we need to find solution for that.

Comment: Yes, they probably have a system that prevents automated mass data entry. They built a system to prevent you from doing _exactly_ what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to post the data using CURL and pass to other page nothing else : http://prntscr.com/mx4wyf

Answer (score 1):

PS: you should probably run this past https://www.reddit.com/r/legaladvice/ (legal advice is out of scope for this website, but what you're trying to do is probably illegal)

it is possible, but very very difficult (because google tried to make it impossible). i know of only 2 services that have managed to do this: www.deathbycaptcha.com /DeathByCaptcha and www.botmasterlabs.net / XRumer - and they have certainly not open-sourced their solutions.

your best best is probably to use the [DeathByCaptcha API](http://deathbycaptcha.com/user/api), which costs money. (and employs real people to solve the actual captchas)