# Is there a way to complete Recaptcha from a curl request?

Tags: php, curl

While working on getting data from an external website it appears I made too many requests by mistake and it triggered a Recaptcha, by the time I made the caching mechanism it was to late, because I can no longer access it.

Using `var_dump(curl_exec($ch))` I can see only part of the website's page getting loaded and a request for completing a Recaptcha, is there a way I can get through this ? I'm stuck

Comment: i think www.deathbycaptcha.com has a solution, but you're probably better off just buying a cheap VPS to act as a proxy and do your requests from a new IP address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post the data with recaptcha verify using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135057/post-the-data-with-recaptcha-verify-using-curl)